# Why do I neeed to use new variable after unwinding in Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I've been playing around (learing) with Cypher. I've created a query that will return list of the cities that are between 190 and 200 distnace units away from London. This is the code:

```
MATCH path=(:City {name: "London"})-\[:Road \* ..2\]-\>(:City)
WITH nodes(path) AS cities, extract(road IN relationships(path) | road.length) AS lengths
UNWIND lengths AS length
WITH cities, sum(length) AS total_length
WHERE total_length \> 150 AND total_length \< 200
UNWIND cities AS city
RETURN DISTINCT city.name, total_length
ORDER BY total_length DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

The code works but I'm having a hard time understaning why is this part needed: `UNWIND lengths AS length`? Why must i create new variable `length`? Could I somehow do the sum directly from unwind?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the new variable `length` to allow the subsequent `WITH` clause to use the `sum(length)` aggregation function to calculate the total length of the roads in the path.

The `UNWIND` clause is used to transform a list of values into individual rows. In this case, it's used to transform the `lengths` list into individual rows containing a single `length` value. This is done to facilitate the use of the `sum(length)` aggregation function, which calculates the total length of the roads in the path by summing up the individual `length` values.

As an alternative, you can achieve the same result by using the `reduce()` function directly on the lengths list to calculate the total length.

```
MATCH path=(:City {name: "London"})-[:Road * ..2]->(:City)
WITH nodes(path) AS cities, [road IN relationships(path) | road.length] AS lengths
WITH cities, reduce(total = 0, l IN lengths | total + l) AS total_length
WHERE total_length > 150 AND total_length < 200
UNWIND cities AS city
RETURN DISTINCT city.name, total_length
ORDER BY total_length DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I get error "Query failed: Not yet implemented: atom expression '[roadINrelationships(path)|road.length]'". It seems that this isn't supported. Thanks